# How to switch my keyboard layout to Colemak layout in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, colemak

I cannot find the US Keyboard layout for Colemak in "*Text Service and Input Languages*" setting dialog. Is there any other way to change the keyboard layout by using software?

I have tried using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 but it seems that I cannot remap CAPS-lock key (BACKSPACE in Colemak).

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Googled "colemak keyboard windows", and the first item returned was "Windows - Colemak - Colemak keyboard layout", but as A Dwarf noted it was down, so I clicked on the cached copy, and then the download button, and that works. You should be able to install it that way.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tMYHu2BWYJkJ:colemak.com/Windows+colemak+keyboard+windows&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com

Click "Download now"

Comment: @A Dwarf Thank you. I was not copying. :) I was just away searching deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the website is down, due to some technical problem. But you can find a download for windows 7 (Vista) here: http://colemak.com/

If you don't want to wait, you can map your keys with the free SharpKeys (it will be able to map your capslock and dead keys): http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html